# Modify sound of incoming Notification in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications

I have set up a `NotificationListenerService` which listens for notifications. I need to modify the sound/alert tone of the notifications which is caught in the method below :

```
override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification?) {
    super.onNotificationPosted(sbn)
    // Modify the tone here and notify ( the notification ) it again
}
```

What I have tried so far ( does not play the sound ):

```
notification.notification.defaults = android.app.Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE
notification.notification.sound = Uri.parse(sharedPreferences.getString(getString( R.string.ringtone_key ) , Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI.toString() ))
manager.notify( RECREATE_NOTIFICATION_ID , notification.notification )
```

My question goes here:

> How can I modify the sound/alert tone of the `StatusBarNotification` caught in the above method and display it to the user? Do I need to repost/recreate it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
{
  if (soundUri != null)
  {
    // Changing Default mode of notification
    notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
    // Creating an Audio Attribute
    val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
    .build()
    // Creating Channel
    val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel("CH_ID", "Testing_Audio", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
    notificationChannel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes)
    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ismail alaoui for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To add some context to ismail alaoui's answer - what you did should probably work for pre-Oreo android devices, but for Oreo and above, you need to create a notification channel, to which the custom sound will be assigned. Refer to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.

Please also remember, that user might change the sound of the notification channel at any moment :)

So only question remaining - which Android version are you testing your solution on?

Comment: Thanks @r2rek. By the way I am testing it with Android Oreo 8.1

Comment: I've discovered that the sound uri is not set in the `Notification` inside `onNotificationPosted` method ONLY IF the user changes the sound uri in the `NotificationChannel` settings. The only way one can retrieve such information is if the developer of the app explicitly sets the sound uri on the notification.